# Membership with recurring fee (monthly or yearly)

Tags: civimember

I really need your advise on how I can solve my problem.
Let me explain first our situation: We have members who pay monthly or yearly his fee. Most of those are paying in cash or bank transfer. What I would like to achieve is that the membership fees are somehow created but pending as long as I did not book the payment. I would like to see an overview of mymembers and if the fee is due or pending. In the Perfect case i would like to put the member to status inactive if he didn‘t pay after 3 months.

I hope it is clear what I need. Otherwise please let me know and i will rephrase it.

Best regards,
Said

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  In general, it's best to ask one question per post, but I'll try to answer both below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mark the payment as pending (see screenshot 1 below) then the resulting membership will be pending.  When you update the payment, the membership will be automatically updated.

To set the member status to Inactive after payment hasn't been received for three months, go to **Administer menu » CiviMember » Membership Status Rules**.  Click **Edit** next to the *Grace* status, and set the end event to "Membership End Date" and "End Event Adjustment" to "3 months".  This creates a three month grace period from the membership end date, and will change to "Expired" after that (assuming you haven't changed other membership status rules).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jon - Thanks for your explaination. I just tried what you wrote and for the first point (Membership Status rules) i was successful in setting it up. Big thank you on that :)